# How can I solve Constructor problem in React?

Tags: reactjs, constructor

I'm a newbie with React.. I'm trying some tutorials with some e-ecommerce app... but with no result..and I can't fix this error with super(props)...Any ideas how to solve this?And after running npm start, my page is all blank...:

> ```
>  class App extends Component {
>       constructor(props) {
>         super(props);
>     
>         this.state = {
>           user: null,
>           cart: {},
>           products: []
>         };
>         this.routerRef = React.createRef();
>       }
>     
>       render() {
>         return (
>           <Context.Provider
>             value={{
>               ...this.state,
>               removeFromCart: this.removeFromCart,
>               addToCart: this.addToCart,
>               login: this.login,
>               addProduct: this.addProduct,
>               clearCart: this.clearCart,
>               checkout: this.checkout
>             }}
>           >
>             <Router ref={this.routerRef}>
>             <div className="App">
>               <nav
>                 className="navbar container"
>                 role="navigation"
>                 aria-label="main navigation"
>               >
>                 <div className="navbar-brand">
>                   <b className="navbar-item is-size-4 ">ecommerce</b>
>                   <label
>                     role="button"
>                     class="navbar-burger burger"
>                     aria-label="menu"
>                     aria-expanded="false"
>                     data-target="navbarBasicExample"
>                     onClick={e => {
>                       e.preventDefault();
>                       this.setState({ showMenu: !this.state.showMenu });
>                     }}
>                   >
>                     <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
>                     <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
>                     <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
>                   </label>
>                 </div>
>                 </nav>
>                 <Routes>
>                   <Route  path="/" element={<ProductList/>}/>
>                   <Route  path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
>                   <Route  path="/cart" element={<Cart/>}/>
>                   <Route  path="/add-product" element={<AddProduct/>}/>
>                   <Route  path="/products" element={<ProductList/>}/>
>                 </Routes>                    
>               </div>
>             </Router>
>           </Context.Provider>
>         );
>       }
>     };
>     export default App;
> ```

And the errors in Chrome [https://imgur.com/a/Eey1KTF]

Comment: can you create a codesandbox link with what you are facing??

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/live/3ac2a6786d6

Comment: there is no context component in the sandbox you shared